# Google Analytics v4 custom events (server side)

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send server side (python requests) events to Google Analytics V4

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX'
url += '&cid={}'.format('click_id')
url += '&ec={}'.format('event_category')
url += '&ea={}'.format('event_action')
url += '&el={}'.format('event_label')
url += '&ni=1'  # 'non_interaction'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': str('user_agent')
}

requests.post(url=url, headers=headers)
```

This works great on V3 of Analytics - when property id is **UA-XXXXXXXXX**.

Now all V4 properties as different id like, **"G-9DXXXXXXXX"** and seems that it's not working.

I didn't find any documentation about V4 events, any help will be very appraised.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send data to  Google Analytics 4 you need to use the [Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)

Sending an event will look something like this

```
const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const api_secret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
    events: [{
      name: 'tutorial_begin',
      params: {},
    }]
  })
});
```

I recommend testing using the [event builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/ga4-event-builder/)  GA4 is a bit tricky, as its still in alpha.

## python

The main change is the fact that you are posting a Json object and not a query string.
I am not the best at python but this is an example of posting a json object it may help.

```
url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}'
payload = {
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
    events: [{
      name: 'tutorial_begin',
      params: {},
    }]
  })
}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer did helped, but we are still struggling there...

Comment: What are your issues?  The main difference is the payload body needs to be a json object not a query string like you are attempting to send now.

Comment: Results status 204 - 'No Content'
I do see now some data on Analytics, but it's count like page views instead of events, as mentioned in the documents.

Comment: What are you using as "client_id"? In a server-to-server scenario, this doesn't make much sense to me, unless you would let the client create a unique ID and route it to the server somehow.

Comment: The measurement protocol sends data to google analytics you don't need a client id to send data to analytics.   THe measurement id is used to state which Google analytics account you are trying to send data to.   You would need a client id to extract data from Google analytics not to it.

Comment: I know this an year old thread, but I am having the same issue still. If I use the event builder interface that google provides, it shows me the event in the anaytics dashboard, but if I use the same request and payload to send via an HTTP request (such as PHP curl or Insomnia) then I get 204 No Content response, but no data is available on the dashboard for that event. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: You could use `/debug/mp/collect` instead of `/mp/collect` for investigating validation errors.